# Two different resource folder in MVC 3 Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

There is a requirement in my project to have two different folders for resource files. I'm taking the key in controller views and also in javascript

Can anyone please help me to achieve this functionality?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can define as many resource files as you want. You just need to write following code for it.

For view

```
@HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("ResourceFileName", "ResourceKeyName")
```

In javascript

```
var str = '@HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("ResourceFileName", "ResourceKeyName")';
```

If its local resource file than simply

For view

```
@ResourceName.ResourceKeyName
```

In javascript

```
var str = '@ResourceName.ResourceKeyName';
```